# Google App Engine Python2.7 local development fails to initialize ctypes dependent libraries

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library, google-app-engine-python

Googles local development server for the App Engine (`dev_appserver.py`) has stopped working for one of my long running projects. The project itself can and has been deployed without issue but throws an error while initializing modules (`numpy` and `PIL`) that call `ctypes` in local development. The error received can be seen below:

```
    import numpy as np
  File "/Users/dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py", line 894, in load_module
    module = self._find_and_load_module(fullname, fullname, [module_path])
  File "/Users/dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py", line 605, in _find_and_load_module
    return imp.load_module(fullname, source_file, path_name, description)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/app-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/app-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from . import numeric
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/app-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 39, in <module>
    from ._internal import TooHardError, AxisError
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/app-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/app-api/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    if int(_os.uname()[2].split('.')[0]) < 8:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I also came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698071/ctypes-init-fails-using-local-app-engine-django-and-virtualenv-with-python-2-7) that has encountered similar issues as of late. Which make me feel it has to do with a recent change in the development server.

I have already tried to update the two packages to the latest 2.7 version as well as downgrading them to the GAE supported versions (`numpy==1.6.1` and `PIL==1.1.7`). Also, removing the modules from the `app.yaml` file as mentioned in the other question seems to make no difference. The `app.yaml` file as used for deployment looks like so:

```
libraries:
- name: PIL
  version: "1.1.7"

- name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"
```

Is anybody aware of changes with regard the development server for working with these libraries?

Comment: are you using mac osx?

Comment: @JorgeHDZ indeed I'm on osx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know issue that only affects to non linux OS

you can try the following workarounds

-- Downgrade your Cloud SDK to v260, this version is working fine on OSX, to do this please run this command

`gcloud components update --version 260.0.0`

-- Or edit the file google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py

In order to remove/comment this package '**_ctypes**' from the array _WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES as is stated in this [Google public case](https://issuetracker.google.com/148656288)

Comment: Thank you @JorgeHDZ! It seems this indeed solves my issue.